# Razor - setting the id of a checkbox in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm looping through a list of vendors on my page, creating a checkbox for each one. I'd like to have each checkbox have an ID like "Vendor1", "Vendor30", where the number is the ID of the vendor.

I have this right now:

```
@foreach (var vendor in Model.Vendors) {
    <input id="@vendor.VendorID" type="checkbox" name="vendors" value="@vendor.VendorID" />
}
```

But that just gives me a number for the ID. I want to add "Vendor" to the front of it.

If I do this:

```
@foreach (var vendor in Model.Vendors) {
    <input id="Vendor@vendor.VendorID" type="checkbox" name="vendors" value="@vendor.VendorID" />
}
```

Every checkbox in the list has an id of "Vendor@vendor.VendorID".

I'm not using `@Html.CheckBox` because of the hidden field that comes along with it, and several other problems it was causing that I didn't include in this example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try wrapping the razor expression in parantheses:

```
<input id="Vendor@(vendor.VendorID)" type="checkbox" name="vendors" value="@vendor.VendorID" />
```

> I'm not using @Html.CheckBox because of the hidden field that comes
>   along with it, and several other problems it was causing that I didn't
>   include in this example.

Personally I've never had any problems with it and would recommend using it.